# Issues with sqoop import from db2 to hdfs

Tags: db2, sqoop, hadoop2, data-ingestion

I am trying to import data from DB2 to hdfs using sqoop. Since I do not have admin permissions to copy db2jcc4.jar to /var/lib/sqoop/ directory, I copied the jar to location where I am executing and specified that jar with --libjars option.

```
    sqoop import \
   --libjars db2jcc4.jar \
   --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver \
   --connect 'jdbc:db2://<hostname>:50000/<dbname>' \
   --username <username> \
   --password <password> \
   --table <tablename> \
   --target-dir /hdfs path
```

I am getting the error as below:

```
   20/04/15 15:16:59 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:875)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1858)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1657)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:494)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue

Comment: JDBC client jars need to be put at $SQOOP_HOME/lib. Can we specify the jars under any custom location and run?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to Db2 requires not just db2jcc4.jar but also its corresponding license JAR, typically db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar or db2jcc_license_cu.jar. The filename of the license JAR to use depends on the operating system of the Db2 server(s) you'll be accessing:

- db2jcc_license_cu.jar can access Linux, UNIX, and Windows Db2 servers
- db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar can access all Db2 server platforms, including z/OS and IBM i

If possible, ask your DBA to provide you with the right release level of db2jcc4.jar and a license JAR that's appropriate for your Db2 environment. Otherwise, you can download the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ for free from IBM at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-db2-fix-packs-version-db2-linux-unix-and-windows. As far as the license JAR is concerned, the JCC drivers available on that website may only include db2jcc_license_cu.jar and not db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar.

Both db2jcc JARs (driver and license) need to be listed in whatever classpath variable is used by your program. For sqoop, the environment variable is `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`, and you may also need to specify the `--libjars` option when running sqoop.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="/tmp/jdbcjars/db2jcc4.jar:/tmp/jdbcjars/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"
sqoop import --libjars /tmp/jdbcjars/db2jcc4.jar,/tmp/jdbcjars/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am trying to find db2jcc_license jar to download, but couldn't get. Do we need to purchase from any provider like IBM or is it open source. If its free, can you provide any link to download

Comment: I revised my answer to include details about the license JAR and where it can be downloaded from IBM's website